# adjacentElementsProduct probleam in CodeSignal - java

Tags: java

I  tried to solve the **adjacentElementsProduct** problem in codesignal and it shows an error **Execution error on test 1: Your program had a runtime error**.
But i did the exact code in my eclipse ide it worked i know a small code compared to the one i mentioned below for this problem  but i want to know whats wrong in my code .

**my code;**

```
int solution(int[] inputArray) {

  int[] b = new int [5];e

  int max=0;
  
  for(int i = 0;i<inputArray.length-1;i++) {
      b[i] = inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
      
      if(b[i]>max) {
          max = b[i];      
      }       
  }
return max;
}
```

Comment: What is the adjacentElementsProduct problem? We don't know what that is.

Comment: it means find the largest pair in a array eg:- 7*3 =21 like that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define your b[] as “b[inputArray.length]” instead of “b[5]”?

If the “inputArray” is larger than 5 your code will break.

Do this:

```
static int solution(int[] inputArray) {

  int[] b = new int[inputArray.length];
...
```

Comment: no now it shows incorrect